# Can we pivot data in Excel using spreadsheetgear

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, spreadsheetgear

I have a scenario to see weather it is possible to pivot data in excel using spreadsheetgear.

We will be sending datatable from application(vb.net) and excel needs to pivot the data and paste in excel cells.

Please let me know if it is possible.

Thank you